# Build a basic Cast Receiver: Casting button does not show

Tags: google-cast

I am following the instructions in the tutorial "[Build a basic Cast Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/codelabs/cast-receiver#0)". I have registered my app following the instruction in stage 4 (Custom Receiver selected, input the URL from ngrok, etc). I ran the server following step 8. The device was restarted.

The Cast button **does** show up in the Cactool V2 if there is no Receiver App ID on the web page, or if I put in the default App ID.

If I enter the Forwarding URL provided by ngrok in a browser, I can see in the browser Dev Tools that the index.html and js/receiver.js are loaded (which is proof that the server is working as expected, even if that's not how the app is designed to be used).

However - the problem - when I enter **my** Receiver App ID in the Cactool V2 as instructed, the Cast button does **not** show up.

One interesting thing - the [Serial Numbers on box and device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Ssx.jpg) are different by one character .... but both do not work.

Would anybody have any suggestions what more may be causing this failure?

Thank you in advance!

**Update:**
My previous attempt was with a *Chromecast with Google TV device* -  with this device the tutorial's Custom Receiver does *not* work.

I have now tried the same Custom Receiver tutorial with *Google Chromecast 3rd generation* - and it works with this receiver.

**Update 2:**
I found that on the *Chromecast with Google TV device* the cast button shows up on any Chrome browser that is logged in with an account **different** from the one that has the Google Cast SDK Developer account setup with the casting application .... !?
See the attached image [Google Cast button with different accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFvjS.png) ... of 4 browsers, only the one that is logged in with the account that registered the device + application does *not* show the cast button!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ... and the code is what's provided in the tutorial - the app-done code ... no code of my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The real series is not the one on the box or the device, you can find the real series by clicking here:[image]